# Folders missing in Home using Nautilus-root

Tags: nautilus, root

So I'm trying to use Nautilus-root to move stuff around, specifically moving `tarballs` to `/usr/local/src` to make them. But when I run Nautilus root, either by making an Applications shortcut by using `sudo nano /usr/share/applications/Nautilus-root.desktop` or by simply running `gksu nautilus`, the folders within "Home" are not there.

I've checked Display Hidden Files and I've also used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to no avail.

I also realize that I can do all this with a `sudo cd` command and I am while I can't use Nautilus. But I would like to be able to use the file browser for some stuff, as going back to Terminal to do everything that requires root can get a bit old.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run nautilus as root (**not** recommended at all) it uses `/root` as home directory. So to access the home directory of your standard user navigate to `File System/home/<yourUser>`.